# I've set up a RNG and a continue button but it wont update the result after continuing

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

```
#Setting up RNG
loop = "y"
while loop == "y" or loop == "yes":
    from random import randint
    dice = (randint(1,10))
    dice2 = (randint(1,10))
    roll = (dice + dice2)
    win = 3
    loss = 2
    cash = 20
    if roll == 3 or roll == 7 or roll == 11 or roll == 17:
        cash += (win)
    else:
        cash -= (loss)
    #Starting game
    print("""Welcome to, Gambling for School!

    You have $20 and must earn as much money as possible

    If you roll a 3, 7, 11, or 17, you will win $3 but any other number 
takes $2

    You have a 20% of winning
""")
    x = input("Press ENTER to start.")
    #Results
    if roll == 11 or roll == 8 or roll == 18:
        print("You rolled an " + str(roll) + "!")
    else:
        print("You rolled a " + str(roll) + "!")
    print("")
    print("Cash - $" + str(cash))
    loop = input("Continue? (Y/N) ").lower()
```

Had to change the indenting to show it as code

When it runs, I hit enter to start the game and it adds and subtracts correctly but when I select continue, it plays as if I never lost or gained any money. It is 1AM and idk if my brain died but I can't think of anything to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You reinitialize the variable `cash` with `20` before every game. To fix the game, just move that code out of the loop.

The initialization of  `win` and `loss` can also be moved out of the loop since they do not change.

Same for the `from random import randint` statement, it is [considered a good practice](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/?#imports) to put all import statements at the top of the file.

```
from random import randint

#Setting up RNG
loop = "y"
win = 3
loss = 2
cash = 20
while loop == "y" or loop == "yes":
    dice = (randint(1,10))
    dice2 = (randint(1,10))
    roll = (dice + dice2)

    if roll == 3 or roll == 7 or roll == 11 or roll == 17:
        cash += win
    else:
        cash -= loss
    #Starting game
    print("""Welcome to, Gambling for School!

You have $20 and must earn as much money as possible

If you roll a 3, 7, 11, or 17, you will win $3 but any other number 
takes $2

You have a 20% of winning
""")
    x = input("Press ENTER to start.")
    #Results
    if roll == 11 or roll == 8 or roll == 18:
        print("You rolled an " + str(roll) + "!")
    else:
        print("You rolled a " + str(roll) + "!")
    print("")
    print("Cash - $" + str(cash))
    loop = input("Continue? (Y/N) ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would reorder your code to make the control-flow more clear.

For comparison "if *a* `in` *several elemets*" you should use [set()s](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#set) - they are very efficient when looking up if something is in them (and for other set-operations).

For printing look up the [str.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/string.html#formatspec) or [python 3.6+ string interpolation: PEP-498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)

You only ever use the sum of 2 random numbers, you can get them in one go using [random.choices(iterable, k=2)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices)

```
from random import choices

cash = 20
winAmount = 3
lossAmount = 2

#Starting game
print("""Welcome to, Gambling for School!

    You have $20 and must earn as much money as possible

    If you roll a 3, 7, 11, or 17, you will win $3, else you loose $2

    You have a 20% chance of winning
""")
x = input("Press ENTER to start.")

lucky_numbers = {3,7,11,17}

# needed for outputting text
pluralize = {8,11,18}
win = False


loop = "y"
while loop and loop[0]== "y":
    sum_dice = sum(choices(range(1,11), k=2))

    if sum_dice in lucky_numbers:
        win = True
        cash += winAmount
    else:
        win = False
        cash -= lossAmount

    print("You {}. You rolled a{} {}!".format(
        "won" if win else "lost",
        "n" if sum_dice in pluralize else "", 
        sum_dice))

    print("")
    print("Cash - $" + str(cash))
    loop = input("Continue? (Y/N) ").lower().strip()
```

Output:

```
Welcome to, Gambling for School!

    You have $20 and must earn as much money as possible

    If you roll a 3, 7, 11, or 17, you will win $3, else you loose $2

    You have a 20% of winning

Press ENTER to start.
You lost. You rolled a 6!

Cash - $18
Continue? (Y/N) y
You lost. You rolled a 16!

Cash - $16
Continue? (Y/N) y
You lost. You rolled a 16!

Cash - $14
Continue? (Y/N) y
You lost. You rolled a 15!

Cash - $12
Continue? (Y/N) y
You won. You rolled a 7!

Cash - $15
Continue? (Y/N) n
```

Beside print formatting the outputs use a ternary (do *x* if this else *y*) operator. More here: [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)